# Is the Airy function normalizable?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, hilbert-space, schroedinger-equation, normalization

I mean the [Airy function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function) as an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian

$$ H = \frac{p^2}{2m } - F x .  $$

Is it normalizable or not?

Comment: The site you quoted says that $\int_{\mathbb R} Ai(t+x)Ai(t+y) dt = \delta(x-y)$ which implies that the function cannot belong to $L^2(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: Yes, it is normalizable to a $\delta$ function. You can find a detailed treatment e.g. in Landau-Lifshitz Vol. 3, where it is explained how to calculate the normalization constant using the asymptotic form of $Ai(x)$